# How to change the color of a cell or row of a table in libre impress

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

How to change the color of a cell or row of a table in libre impress (not libre office writer)

Comment: Please upload the Inpress presentation and provide a link to it in a comment.

Comment: Go to cell and then from menu: Format → Table → Properties... → Background. Change color.

Comment: Frent belowom Format menu, I did not get Table Properties. I m using Ubuntu 18.04, but my problem is solved. Please see my comm

Answer (score 1):

There are some serious usability issues with this aspect of Impress tables indeed. It is not quite obvious how a row can be selected using the mouse or the keyboard.

Marvelously hidden in the Table Toolbar, you can reveal buttons to select a row or a column. Right click on an empty space on the toolbar, and in the menu, enable these buttons one by one from the "Visible buttons" menu.

I am not aware of other options to select individual rows or cells. If they are there, they are equally undiscovered as the option I have shown.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I clicked on the 'Visible Buttons' from the table icon, then made grid active, later deactivated it to test. But now every time I insert a table using insert menu or from table icon, I get a menu down below related to table editing. like insert, delete a row/column, change color, change text alignment in a cell. Thanks again

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you. Click the checkmark next to the question.